# Error in implementing OpenStreetMap

Tags: android, android-studio, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I am trying to implement OpenStreetMap in android studio. I successfully added the libraries as shown below.

[image]

This is my MainActivity:

```
package com.example.re.osm;

import org.osmdroid.views.MapController;
import org.osmdroid.views.MapView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.example.harjotkaur.osm.R;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private MapView myOpenMapView;
        private MapController myMapController;

        /** Called when the activity is first created. */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            myOpenMapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
            myOpenMapView.seharjotkaurtBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            myMapController = myOpenMapView.getController();
            myMapController.setZoom(4);
        }

    }
```

This is my build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.re.osm"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile files('libs/slf4j-android-1.5.8.jar')
compile files('libs/osmdroid-android-3.0.8.jar')

}
```

This is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.re.osm"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="OSM" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="OSM" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

But when I run the aplication, I get to see only small rectangles and not the map.
How should I fix this? What steps should I follow?

Any ideas are appreciated?

Thanks

Comment: Current version of osmdroid library is 5.6.5 Why are you using so ancient version (3.0.8)? It's maybe five years old.

Comment: I am not able to download the 5.6.5 osmdroid library. It take me to this page :https://jar-download.com/explore-java-source-code.php?a=osmdroid-geopackage&g=org.osmdroid&v=5.6.5&downloadable=0  

Which version should I use?

Comment: Follow instructions on osmdroid page: https://osmdroid.github.io/osmdroid/ and use gradle dependency. If you cannot use gradle you can download it here: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/releases

Comment: Yes. Did that it worked perfectly. I successfully got the world map set to a particular set of geo co-ordinates. Any ideas on How do I get the current user location?

Comment: @Thomas Please follow this link for getting the current location.
https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html
It would be great if you can also upvote my answer.

Comment: @Waleed Sarwar. Yes i did that. How can I do this in case of osmdroid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
import com.exercise.OpenStreetMapView.R;
```

with this:

```
import com.example.re.osm.R;
```

Comment: I updated my question with the import statements. What should I change?

Comment: @Thomas I have edited my answers. Did you try it?.If it doesn't work add your package import in the question.